# Image's size responsive to scrolling

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to code up website logo that the size would be smaller once scrolls down like the one on this website https://infrared.cni.columbia.edu/ . I'm new to html and wondering if there's any commands that can define the size of the image along scrolling.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You have to use JavaScript. Specifically the `onscroll` method. That should get you started.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do this without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly what youre trying to do and its actually very easy

Start with something similar to this on the CSS of the image (The transitions will allow for a really smooth animated transition without a library like jQuery doing custom variable changes like opacity and size which can slow load time)

```
.logo {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s ease,opacity .3s ease,background-color .3s ease;
    -o-transition: height .4s ease,opacity .3s ease,background-color .3s ease;
    transition: height .4s ease,opacity .3s ease,background-color .3s ease
}
```

Now with javascript, after a certain amount of scrolling, add a class to the image that will modify its height;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict
    var scrollInital = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowWInitial = $(window).width();
    if (scrollInital >= 2) {//2 is the scroll down amount, I like to have mine instantly go down on any length of scroll but customize to your needs.
        $("#header").addClass("sticky-header");
    }else{
        $("#header").removeClass("sticky-header");
    }
}
```

So now your image tag just has another CSS variable that has the sticky-header in itr aswell

```
.logo .sticky-header {
    height: 60px;
}
```

So when it hits whatever scroll length youd like, simply set the height and it will adjust.

What I suggest is learning to inspect element with Chrome Devtools (F12 on windows) and see how others do it, you can even create breakpoints and see when javascript intervenes.

This is pretty much exactly my websites code if you wanted to look and try inspecting element and learning that way; [TechGorilla](https://techgorilla.io)

**Note** I used jQuery to do this, I would recommend you get jQuery and learn it as it will save alot of time and is essentially used on every major webpage that isnt running a framework like React or Angular

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for responding. But I'm actually really unfamiliar with java script. Could you tell me how to input it in html? lol I'm pretty bad at this. If possible do you mind if i send you the code to the website and you can help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript isn't needed here. only html and css would it by creating your company website with html canvas and then add a meta tag for viewport so that your image sizes according to the size and you can also max-width : 100% for the logo so that it doesn't get oversized.